# Only show price when is_archive woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce, I don't want to display the price on the product archive. I use the code:

`remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );`

This works fine. But it removes the price on ervery block were i'm showing products. I only want to execute the code on a archive page.

I tried the code:

```
if (is_archive()) { 
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    }
```

It does not work.
I did a lot of research and found some articles about loading hierarchy. This made sense. In a few other cases i used `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'delete_price_test');'. This did the job for hooks who are in my theme.

```
function delete_price_test() {
    if (is_archive()) { 
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'delete_price_test');
```

I dont get my code working. I tried everything, searched the forum, googled, and so on but no solution. Could somebody please help me with this isue?

Kr, Frans

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
/**
* Hide price everywhere ( exclude category page)
*/

function bml_not_hide_prices_on_all_categories( $price, $product ) {

    if ( is_product_category() ) {
        return $price;
    }

    return ''; // Empty string = no price!

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bml_not_hide_prices_on_all_categories', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This code is hides the price but in my case i'm removing the price and add the price later in another block. So first i want to remove the price, later on i want to add the price. Removing and adding the price is working but I only want to do it on the product category page so i want to use an IF statement.